# Remove low frequency values from pandas.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I remove values from a column in `pandas.DataFrame`, that occurs rarely, i.e. with a low frequency? Example:

```
In [4]: df[col_1].value_counts()

Out[4]: 0       189096
        1       110500
        2        77218
        3        61372
              ...
        2065         1
        2067         1
        1569         1
        dtype: int64
```

So, my question is: how to remove values like `2065, 2067, 1569` and others? And how can I do this for ALL columns, that contain `.value_counts()` like this?

***UPDATE:*** About 'low' I mean values like `2065`. This value occurs in `col_1` 1 (one) times and I want to remove values like this.

Comment: What do you mean by "meet rarely"? Can you be more specific? Adding some code that you already tried might help.

Comment: I can't understand how can be "more specific"? In ```col_1``` value like ```0``` meet ```189096``` times. And value like ```1569``` meet ONE times. I want to remove ```1569``` and other values like this in ```col_1```.

Comment: Aha! You mean "occurs", not "meets".

Comment: Now if you provide a self-containing piece of code that generates a similar data structure it will be much easier to come up with an answer.

Comment: OK. My English is bad and I know it. But I work about it =). So, what about my question?

Comment: Ideally the question would provide a self-contained piece of code generating the data structure, or even just something like `df = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]]`, enough to try to get an answer without diving into panda.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I see there are two ways you might want to do this.

**For the entire DataFrame**

This method removes the values that occur infrequently in the entire DataFrame.  We can do it without loops, using built-in functions to speed things up.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, high=9, size=(100,2)),
         columns = ['A', 'B'])

threshold = 10 # Anything that occurs less than this will be removed.
value_counts = df.stack().value_counts() # Entire DataFrame 
to_remove = value_counts[value_counts <= threshold].index
df.replace(to_remove, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

**Column-by-column**

This method removes the entries that occur infrequently in each column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, high=9, size=(100,2)),
         columns = ['A', 'B'])

threshold = 10 # Anything that occurs less than this will be removed.
for col in df.columns:
    value_counts = df[col].value_counts() # Specific column 
    to_remove = value_counts[value_counts <= threshold].index
    df[col].replace(to_remove, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm missing a piece of logic, can someone please  explain why you need the ".index" (or ".values" below) for the code to work, TIA

Comment: @eli - it's because value_counts is a series and the .index is the value that you want to remove.

Answer (score 8):

You probably don't want to remove the entire row in your DataFrame if only one column has values below your threshold, so I've simply removed these data points and replaced them with `None`.

I loop through each column and perform a `value_counts` on each.  I then get the index values for each items that occurs at or below the target threshold values.  Finally, I use `.loc` to locate these elements values in the column and then replace them with `None`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], 
                   'B': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'], 
                   'C': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']})

>>> df
   A  B  C
0  a  a  a
1  b  a  a
2  b  b  b
3  c  c  b
4  c  c  c

threshold = 1  # Remove items less than or equal to threshold
for col in df:
    vc = df[col].value_counts()
    vals_to_remove = vc[vc <= threshold].index.values
    df[col].loc[df[col].isin(vals_to_remove)] = None

>>> df
      A     B     C
0  None     a     a
1     b     a     a
2     b  None     b
3     c     c     b
4     c     c  None
```

Comment: Thank you! That exactly what I asked

Answer (score 0):

With [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) this can be accomplished in one line. [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) returns the counts of unique values.
The occurences are mapped to each value with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) replaces all values where the condition
is not met (*here*: number of occurences is greater than 1) with *NaN*.

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], 'B': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'],  'C': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']})

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   A  B  C
0  a  a  a
1  b  a  a
2  b  b  b
3  c  c  b
4  c  c  c

In [8]: df.apply(lambda col: col.where(col.map(col.value_counts()) > 1))
Out[8]: 
     A    B    C
0  NaN    a    a
1    b    a    a
2    b  NaN    b
3    c    c    b
4    c    c  NaN
```

Credits to @Alexander for the dataset.