# Replace low frequency categorical values from pandas.dataframe while ignoring NaNs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can I replace the values from certain columns in a pandas.DataFrame that occur rarely, i.e. with low frequency (while ignoring NaNs)?

For example, in the following dataframe, suppose I wanted to replace any values in columns A or B that occur less than three times in their respective column. I want to replace these with "other":

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['ant','ant','cherry', pd.np.nan, 'ant'], 'B':['cat','peach', 'cat', 'cat', 'peach'], 'C':['dog','dog',pd.np.nan, 'emu', 'emu']})
df
   A   |   B   |  C  |
----------------------
ant    | cat   | dog |
ant    | peach | dog |
cherry | cat   | NaN |
NaN    | cat   | emu |
ant    | peach | emu |
```

In other words, in columns A and B, I want to replace those values that occur twice or less (but leave NaNs alone).

So the output I want is:

```
   A   |   B   |  C  |
----------------------
ant    | cat   | dog |
ant    | other | dog |
other  | cat   | NaN |
NaN    | cat   | emu |
ant    | other | emu |
```

This is related to a previously posted question: [Remove low frequency values from pandas.dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511061/remove-low-frequency-values-from-pandas-dataframe)

but the solution there resulted in an "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'any.'"  (I think because I have NaN values?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is pretty similar to [Change values in pandas dataframe according to value_counts()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239627/change-values-in-pandas-dataframe-according-to-value-counts/37240455#37240455). You can add a condition to the lambda function to exclude column 'C' as follows:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.mask(x.map(x.value_counts())<3, 'other') if x.name!='C' else x)
Out: 
       A      B    C
0    ant    cat  dog
1    ant  other  dog
2  other    cat  NaN
3    NaN    cat  emu
4    ant  other  emu
```

This basically iterates over columns. For each column, it generates value counts and uses that Series for mapping. This allows `x.mask` to check the condition whether the count is smaller than 3 or not. If that is the case, it returns 'other' and if not it uses the actual value. Lastly, a condition checks the column name.

lambda's condition can be generalized for multiple columns by changing it to `x.name not in 'CDEF'` or `x.name not in ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F']` from `x.name!='C'`.

Answer (score 4):

using a helper function and `replace`

```
def replace_low_freq(df, threshold=2, replacement='other'):
    s = df.stack()
    c = s.value_counts()
    m = pd.Series(replacement, c.index[c <= threshold])
    return s.replace(m).unstack()

cols = list('AB')
replace_low_freq(df[cols]).join(df.drop(cols, 1))

       A      B    C
0    ant    cat  dog
1    ant  other  dog
2  other    cat  NaN
3   None    cat  emu
4    ant  other  emu
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
#added one last row for complicated df
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['ant','ant','cherry', pd.np.nan, 'ant', 'd'], 
                   'B':['cat','peach', 'cat', 'cat', 'peach', 'm'], 
                   'C':['dog','dog',pd.np.nan, 'emu', 'emu', 'k']})
print (df)
        A      B    C
0     ant    cat  dog
1     ant  peach  dog
2  cherry    cat  NaN
3     NaN    cat  emu
4     ant  peach  emu
5       d      m    k
```

Use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for find all values for replace:

```
a = df.A.value_counts()
a = a[a < 3].index
print (a)
Index(['cherry', 'd'], dtype='object')

b = df.B.value_counts()
b = b[b < 3].index
print (b)
Index(['peach', 'm'], dtype='object')
```

And then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `dict comprehension` if more values for replacing:

```
df.A = df.A.replace({x:'other' for x in a})
df.B = df.B.replace({x:'other' for x in b})
print (df)
       A      B    C
0    ant    cat  dog
1    ant  other  dog
2  other    cat  NaN
3    NaN    cat  emu
4    ant  other  emu
5  other  other    k
```

All together in loop:

```
cols = ['A','B']
for col in cols:
    val = df[col].value_counts()
    y = val[val < 3].index
    df[col] = df[col].replace({x:'other' for x in y})
print (df)
       A      B    C
0    ant    cat  dog
1    ant  other  dog
2  other    cat  NaN
3    NaN    cat  emu
4    ant  other  emu
5  other  other    k
```

Comment: Hmm, so this works on this sample df, but when I try to do this with my actual data, I get an error with the replace w/dict comprehension line: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0). Any idea what might be going on there?

Comment: I am not sure, maybe is necessary convert to list - `df[col] = df[col].replace({x:'other' for x in y.tolist()})`