# Dropping rows in Dataframe: labels not contained in axis

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with three columns: `user_id`, `book_id` and `rating`. So, one row shows what rating a user gave to a book.

I'm trying to remove rows that correspond to users who rated less than 10 books. I did something similar to what is described in answers to this question [Remove low frequency values from pandas.dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511061/remove-low-frequency-values-from-pandas-dataframe) . Here is my code:

```
threshold = 10
value_counts = ratings['user_id'].value_counts()
to_remove = value_counts[value_counts <= threshold].index
ratings.drop(to_remove, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

When I run it, I get an error in the last line:

```
ValueError: labels [40518 21743 30824 <...> 47178 46308 30460] not contained in axis
```

The table has 979478 rows, so the rows with these indices should exist. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `isin`, cause, the user_id is not the index , we can not using `.drop` here.

```
threshold = 10
value_counts = ratings['user_id'].value_counts()
to_remove = value_counts[value_counts <= threshold].index
ratings.loc[~ratings['user_id'].isin(to_remove),:]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works correctly now!
Does `to_remove` contain user IDs and not numbers of rows then?

Comment: @vgeclair yes, it is the value not the index. :-),`value_counts` return a `pd.Serise`